# Using require() in javascript in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Ok a very basic question, but I'm completely new to Javascript.

So I'm using Javascript in a Rails project, I need to use Uppy, a lib for image uploading, but whatever, this a general question on including Javascript libraries in Rails. I included the required library in my project using npm, and I included the location of the index.js file in application.js like

```
//= require @uppy/core/src/index.js
```

Now checking from the console, this is loading alright. 
Now in my view file, views/photos/new.html.erb I included the script suggested in Uppy that begins with

```
<script>
// Import the plugins
const Uppy = require('@uppy/core')
const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload')
const Dashboard = require('@uppy/dashboard')

</script>
```

I'm getting error `require is not defined`
Now I understand that since I used the require in application.js I do not need to reuse the "javascript" way in the script I'm writing. What should I do instead however to initialize the variables Uppy, XHRUplad and Dashboard?

Comment: You could write the JS code directly in application.js, then activate it only when a certain element renders.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example :) 
What I need basically now is to define a const called Uppy = require('@uppy/core'). How can I do this when using //= require

Comment: `require()` is a node.js thing. To do this in a browser I think you would need to use a package like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or equivalent.

Comment: `//= require` comes from the Sprockets asset packaging system. You're trying to use `require()` which probably comes from Browserify or Webpack. Try using [Rails Webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker).

Comment: @mrateb This article explains how to use Uppy with Rails. https://medium.com/@maxencemalbois/rails-multiple-direct-uploads-to-s3-with-shrine-and-uppy-with-live-versionning-thanks-to-an-ajax-6482b85dad2b